# How to return adjacent cell value of the lowest cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm trying to use VLOOKUP formula from [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2590-excel-vlookup-lowest-value.html#a1%5D%5B1%5D) but it doesn't work for me for some reason. It shows `#N/A`. How could I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your arguments is wrong. The second argument of VLOOKUP must be a table. However, your referenced table is only cells from column B. Elements from the second column (according to your formula) that you want to return are not found. That's why you get `#N/A`. Your formula should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(A44:A52),A44:B52,2,0)
```

[image]